# How to call init method or specific function again when we click on already activated bottom menu

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I have implemented following BottomNavigation

```
class AppMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppMenu> createState() => _AppMenuState();
}

class _AppMenuState extends State<AppMenu> {
  int current = 0;
  final List<String> titles = [
    "Home 1",
    "Home 2"
  ];

  final List<Widget> views = [
    const HomeView1(),
    const HomeView2(),
  ];
  final List<String> icons = [
    "icon_1",
    "icon_2",
  ];

  final List<String> barTitles = ["Home1", "Home2"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: HomeAppBar(
        title: titles[current],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              current = index;
            });
          },
          selectedItemColor: const Color(0xff6B6B6B),
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          unselectedItemColor: const Color(0xff6B6B6B),
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          items: views.map((e) {
            final itemIndex = views.indexOf(e);
            return BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/${icons[itemIndex]}${itemIndex == current ? "" : "_disabled"}.png",
                  width: 25,
                ),
              ),
              label: barTitles[itemIndex],
            );
          }).toList()),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: views[current]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now it works perfect when I click on home1 and home2 bottom menu and it shows respected widget and load all the content which I have wrote on initState of home1 and home2 but now assume that I am on home1 and if I click again home1 then it is not calling initState again.

I want to call initState or specific function if user click on that menu even if it is selected.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html

Comment: I guess not relevant

Comment: this is a widget that allows you to get build again in some cases. you want to get build again, just put inside this widget what you want these things to build

Comment: I want to build again when we click again on the menu even if it is selected.

Comment: just tell to widget, I want to build you again if I click again on the menu, with a bool

Comment: That I know but how to tell widget?

Comment: can you provide, the codes that you want to call again in initState

Comment: Just use any function that gives data from API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a initialize or initXXX function to initialize something in initState or somewhere. If parent widget call setState(), then child widget will call didUpdateWidget().

```
void initialize() {
  // do something
}
```

Call initialize() in initState().

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initialize();
}
```

Call initialize() in didUpdateWidget() of page(child widget).

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant PageTest oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  initialize();
}
```

Comment: how to call didUpdateWidget method ? i mean inti is load on page load but how we can call didUpadateWidget method on button click

Answer (score -1):

To handle the case in a simple way. You can add your method in `onTap` of `BottomNavigationBar` and then pass your data down to the widget tree.

> It's only a demonstration to handle your case, you can adjust it with your own liking

For example

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          onTap: (index) {
            if(current == index){
                foo = yourMethodHere();
                }
            setState(() {
              current = index;
            });
          },
```

Pass the variable in the tree

```dart
  List<Widget> get views => [
    HomeView1(foo),
    HomeView2(foo),
  ];
```